# Нужна ли запятая перед первым союзом "и" в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

На рассвете сгущался туман, и капли падали на листики берёзы, и листики с каплями, тяжелея, отрывались и падали на землю.
Является ли "на рассвете" общим для грамматических основ членом, что должно означать написание между первыми двумя грамматическими основами без запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это цитата из Пришвина: https://freelibrary.ru/bookread/189822-mihail-prishvin-tom-7-nataska-romki-glaza-zemli/page-86

Как можно видеть, у автора стоит запятая: ***На рассвете сгущался туман, и капли падали на листики берёзы, и листики с каплями, тяжелея, отрывались и падали на землю.***

Так что остается только **объяснить**  постановку знаков препинания. Автор не считает "на рассвете" общим обстоятельством, так как это не входит в его художественную задачу.

Это сложносочиненное предложение, в которым перечисляется последовательность событий:  вот сгущается туман,  капли начинают падать на листья, а потом уже отяжелевшие листья падают на землю. **Перечислительная, плавная** интонация в большей степени подходит для такого изображения действия. Если не поставить запятую, то два первых предложения будут произноситься в одну фразу, а все предложение будет состоять из двух частей. Но автор выбрал другой вариант.

Все глаголы **несовершенного** вида, они обозначают повторяющийся процесс. А последовательность действия на каждом этапе этого процесса обозначается сочинительными **союзами И**.